# how to identify quantity of an entity

Tags: database

i am new to database, i m creating database of a bakery. In my database i have a Product entity,
 what i cant figure out is that how to identify number of products. 
Attributes of Product are Pro_ID, Pro_Name, P_Type , P_price ,P_description ,P_Size.

Now suppose Pro_ID is primary key and if i want to add pizza as a product type and bakery have 1000 chicken tikka pizzas , so do i have to add 1000 rows with same info just with different Pro_ID or should i add a quantity attribute in a product entity.

How do i make this entity so that when customer buy a specific product, database will delete or decrease the quantity of product.

My other question is can i change the attribute using SQL after making a Database and decrease in quantity of a product ?

and last question is Pro_ID is enough to uniquely identify a row or should i need to make a composite key of Pro_ID and Pro_Type as bakery have cakes salads pizzas etc ?

Answer (score 0):

1) you can add another attribute name pro_qyt, where your quantity on product will store,

2) you can increase or decrease a column value using query but if the attribute has a numeric value..

3) yes you can change the attribute using SQL after making a Database and decrease in quantity of a 
product.

4) It's depend on you, you can also make a 4 or more digit random key using php that can uniquely identify a row......